# Grouping pairs of records in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer matching table which contains pairs of customer IDs like below.

```
PAIR_ID     CUST_ID MATCH_CUST_ID
12345       800001  900001
12346       800002  900001
12347       800003  900001
12348       800004  900002
12349       900003  900004
12350       900004  900005
12351       900004  900006
```

I want to create separate groups which contain all of the customer ids that are linked.

For example,

Group 1:

```
800001
800002
800003
900001
```

Group 2:

```
800004
900002
```

Group 3:

```
900003
900004
900005
900006
```

Is there an easy way to do this to ensure that I don't miss out on any pair that should be contained in a group?

Comment: I would say that there will not be an easy way if same id can occur in `CUST_ID` and in `MATCH_CUST_ID` in different rows.

Comment: Please define the exact condition that needs to be satisfied to consider two IDs ***linked***.

Comment: Have you any pattern for your groups?

Comment: Its a case of inferring a link. If A is linked to B and B is linked to C, therefore A is also linked to C.

Comment: What parameter given to query so its returning *group 1* or *group n*? is it the `CUST_ID` or `MATCH_CUST_ID` or what?

Comment: I just want to run a query across the entire table to group all the records that are linked either directly or via association in another pair.

Comment: Similar to adding a dense rank to give them a unique group id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blow should make a trick:

```
with cpair (PAIR_ID, CUST_ID, MATCH_CUST_ID) 
as 
(select 12345, 800001, 900001 from dual
 union all 
 select 12346, 800002, 900001 from dual
 union all 
 select 12347, 800003, 900001 from dual
 union all 
 select 12348, 800004, 900002 from dual
 union all 
 select 12349, 900003, 900004 from dual
 union all 
 select 12350, 900004, 900005 from dual
  union all 
 select 12351, 900004, 900006 from dual) ,  
tree  (mainid, custid, matchcustid, path) as 
( select cust_id, cust_id, match_cust_id, to_char(pair_id) 
from cpair
union all
select mainid,
    case when ( p.CUST_ID = t.matchcustid )  then p.CUST_ID
         when ( p.MATCH_CUST_ID = t.matchcustid )  then p.match_CUST_ID
         when (  p.cust_id = t.custid )  then p.CUST_ID
         when ( p.match_cust_id = t.custid )  then p.match_CUST_ID   
    end,
    case when ( p.CUST_ID = t.matchcustid )  then p.MATCH_CUST_ID
         when ( p.MATCH_CUST_ID = t.matchcustid )  then p.CUST_ID
         when (  p.cust_id = t.custid )  then p.MATCH_CUST_ID
         when ( p.match_cust_id = t.custid )  then p.CUST_ID   
    end, 
    t.path || '-' || to_char(p.PAIR_ID) 
from tree t
join cpair p
on 
 ( p.CUST_ID = t.matchcustid 
 or p.MATCH_CUST_ID = t.matchcustid 
 or p.cust_id = t.custid 
 or p.match_cust_id = t.custid 
 ) 
 and instr(path, pair_id ) < 1   
  ),
distinctTree as 
(
  select distinct mainid, matchcustid
   from tree
  union all 
   select distinct mainid, mainid 
   from tree
  order by mainid ),
treeGroup as (
  select mainid, listagg(matchcustid, ',') within group (order by matchcustid) custList 
  from distinctTree
  group by mainid )
  select distinct custlist from treeGroup
```

Result :

```
CustList
-------------
800004,900002
900003,900004,900005,900006
800001,800002,800003,900001
```

The query goes recursively through customer relation's tree and creates list of  related customers for each customer. After that , the list of related customer is changed to string that is used to group. From grouping we can see with customers belongs to which group.

Comment: Impressive solution!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for this. Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

```
with T0 as (--input data
select 12345 as pair_id,800001 as cust_id,900001 as mutch_cust_id from dual
union all
select 12346,       800002,  900001 from dual
union all
select 12347,       800003,  900001 from dual
union all
select 12348,       800004,  900002 from dual
union all
select 12349 ,      900003,  900004 from dual
union all
select 12350,       900004,  900005 from dual
union all 
select 12351,       900004,  900006 from dual

),
T1 as (--input data + mirror
select pair_id, cust_id, mutch_cust_id, 'input' as sign from t0
union all
select pair_id, mutch_cust_id, cust_id, 'mirror' from t0
)
--result 
select  max(CONNECT_BY_ROOT x.pair_id) "group", x.cust_id
from T1 x
start with x.sign='input'
connect by nocycle prior x.cust_id=x.mutch_cust_id 
group by x.cust_id
order by 1,2
```